# CORS issue from AWS API GATEWAY when accessing from web for Bad request scenario

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I am trying to integrate Rest API (Middleware Backend application) in AWS API GATEWAY which will acts as a pass through, I have configured API and enabled CORS in GATEWAY.
When I am trying to access the Gateway integrated API from Web , API throwing ***“CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource””*** when I am hitting with a bad request 4XX status codes and for success scenarios its returning success response, it means which return 200 status code.

Is there any way to configure API Gateway to receive 4XX responses without throwing CORS issue.

I tried to look into AWS API GATEWAY for allowing CORS origin settings for bad request scenarioes but no options found.
I am looking for a solution to avoid CORS error when performing testing with a bad request.

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Comment: I understand that above scenario is about a middleware API configured behind API Gateway which is causing CORS error when tried with bad requests.

Comment: May be something from frontend or API Gateway should have some option to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

**The question s quite vague, but let me do some guessing about what the problem is.**

May it be that the resource behind your AWS API Gateway has a CORS policy implemented? Maybe it's an s3 bucket with some CORS policy attached. If created with Cloud Formation it will have this configuration with CORS:

```yaml
BucketName:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      CorsConfiguration:
```

In that case, when the browser does a preflight request to check CORS policy, it will hit your resource if it exists, and get the CORS policy back. If the browser is happy with the policy, it will do the actual request. But when it is trying to access a resource that does not exist, a file in the bucket that are not there, the resource is not found and can for that reason not answer with a CORS policy.

If you setup your AWS API Gateway using an `openapi`-definition, check out the top level property `x-amazon-apigateway-cors:`.

If you have a Cloud Front infront of your API Gateway, and that is setup using Cloud Formation, you can set CORS policy on that using:

```yaml
  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      ...
      DistributionConfig:
        ...
        CacheBehaviors:
            ...
            ResponseHeadersPolicyId: !Ref ResponseHeadersPolicy

  ResponseHeadersPolicy:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::ResponseHeadersPolicy
    Properties:
      ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig:
        CorsConfig:
          ...
          AccessControlAllowMethods:
            Items:
              - GET
              - HEAD
              - OPTIONS
          AccessControlAllowOrigins:
            Items:
              - https://example.com
```